# Copy files and directory using devc++ with c++ language

Tags: c++, windows, dev-c++

How can I create a directory in 
c:/'Program Files'/blablabla
 using c++?

I also want to copy some files in blablabla folder. For example, test.exe, how do I implement this in c++ language?

Also, how to make shortcut in desktop to connect with test.exe in blabla folder.

I'm using devc++ version 4.9.9.2 and windows 7, can someone help me? Thanks for ur help.

edit:
i got this code

```
fstream f("FILE.EXTENSION", fstream::in|fstream::binary);
f << noskipws;
istream_iterator<unsigned char> begin(f);
istream_iterator<unsigned char> end;

fstream f2("c:\\FILE.EXTENSION",
fstream::out|fstream::trunc|fstream::binary);
ostream_iterator<char> begin2(f2);

copy(begin, end, begin2);
```

the probleam appear when i'm trying to copy shortcut or folder, can somebody help me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In native C++ you can't copy directory, you can copy files (i.e. create new file and copy information from old file to new file), but without using non-standard libs you cannot create directory. You can look to `WINApi` for this or to `boost`.

For create directory and copy files use for example [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), or some `OS-dependent` API.

Example of create dir:

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path dir_p("/home/blabla");
if (!fs::exists(dir_p))
{
   if (!fs::create_directory(dir_p))
   {
      // error
   }
}
```

Comment: i got many error using this code, can u tell me more more clearly? from the begining? i'm using devc++ so i need what file needed to include,, thanks before

Comment: @user1533670 it's boost library. look at the link.

Comment: @user1533670 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/index.html

Comment: how about copy folder and shortcut? I have found a code that can copy file with extension, but how to copy file that doesn't have extension like folder or shortcut?

Comment: @user1533670 dir/symlink/file http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy